# How do I make a new call to an api when a previous one finished successfully?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am new to angular and rxjs, and I have the following scenario, in which I need that after a call to an api is successfully resolved to make a new call, in the context of angular / rxjs I don't know how to do it

```
handler(): void {
  this.serviceNAme
    .createDirectory(this.path)
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.someProperty = false;
      })
    )
    .subscribe(
      (data) => console.log(data),
      (error) => console.error(error.message)
    );
}
```

What is the correct way to make a new call to an api when a previous one was successful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand you have a `serviceOne` and a `serviceTwo`. And you want to call `serviceTwo` using the retrieved data from `serviceOne`.

Using rxjs [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) you can pipe one observable into another.

```js
    handler(): void {
        this.serviceOne
            .createDirectory(this.path)
            .pipe(
                switchMap(serviceOneResult => {
                    // transform data as you wish
                    return this.serviceTwo.methodCall(serviceOneResult);
                })
            )
            .subscribe({
                next: serviceTwoResult => {
                    // here we have the data returned by serviceTwo
                },
                error: err => {},
            });
    }
```

---

If you don't need to pass the data from `serviceOne` to `serviceTwo` but you need them to be both completed together, you could use rxjs [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin).

```js
    handler(): void {
        forkJoin([
            this.serviceOne.createDirectory(this.path), 
            this.serviceTwo.methodCall()
        ])
        .subscribe({
            next: ([serviceOneResult, serviceTwoResult]) => {
                // here we have data returned by both services
            },
            error: err => {},
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `aysnc` and `await` you can do:

```
async handler(): void {
  await this.serviceNAme
    .createDirectory(this.path)
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.someProperty = false;
      })
    )
    .subscribe(
      (data) => console.log(data),
      (error) => console.error(error.message)
    );

   // Do second api call
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Won't the second call get executed if the first one failed too?

Comment: Correct, you'll need to do some exception/error handling in additional to this, like wrapping it with a `try { } catch {}` for example.

Comment: Following the line of `async` `await`. In the first call I handle that regardless if the response is successful or not at the end I perform an action, in this context of `async` `await` to preserve this I should then use `try` `catch` `finally`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few says to do this:

#### Scenario # 1

Your two service api calls are independent, you just want one to go and then the next

```
 const serviceCall1 = this.serviceName.createDirectory(this.path);
 const serviceCall2 = this.serviceName.createDirectory(this.otherPath);

 concat(serviceCall1 , serviceCall2).subscribe({
   next: console.log,
   error: err => console.error(err.message),
   complete: () => console.log("service call 1&2 complete")
 });
```

#### Scenario # 2

Your two calls dependant on one another, so you need the result of the first before you can start the second

```
 this.serviceName.getDirectoryRoot().pipe(
   switchMap(root => this.serviceName.createDirectoryInRoot(root, this.path))
 ).subscribe({
   next: console.log,
   error: err => console.error(err.message),
   complete: () => console.log("service call 1 used to create service call 2, which is complete")
 });
```

---

You'll want **scenario # 2**, because done this way, an error in the first call will mean no result is sent to the `switchMap`, and second call is never made.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Indeed the first scenario is the one that applies in my case, I regret not having commented on it in the question. The only thing I don't see is that in my case I need to perform actions with the data returned by each call to the api, I see next, is next for this?

Comment: @Mario, Mrk Sef comprise the result of the subscription. You can use `subscribe((res)=>{console.log(res)},(error)=>{console.log('an error')},(complete)=>{console.log("the observable is completed")})`

Comment: @Mario - Yeah, `next` `complete` and `error` are call back functions that get called. Here, I just used `console.log`, but you can define them to be anything you'd like. You can also alter your service calls `.pipe(map(...),tap(...))` individually if you'd like more fine-grained control.