# rxjs operators, how to return nested data in a single object?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm unable to find a clean way of fetching nested data the rxjs way.

There's an observable returning all users and an observable returning all posts given a user id.

`getUsers(): Observable<User[]>`

and

`getPosts(id: string): Observable<[]>`

How would I return a list of users including their posts?

At the moment I prepare the data using 2 nested subscriptions.

```js
nestedFetch() {
  this.service.getUsers()
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      res.forEach((user) => {
        this.service.getPosts(user.Id).subscribe(
          posts => {
            user.posts = posts;
            this.users.push(user);
          },
          err => console.log('something went wrong: ' + err)
        )
      })
    },
    err => console.log('something went wrong: ' + err)
  );
}
```

I would rather use operators something like this. But how can i return users including their posts?

```js
nestedFetch() {
  this.service.getUsers().pipe(
    map(users => users.map(u => this.membership.getPosts(u.id))),
    mergeMap(posts => forkJoin(posts))
  ).subscribe(
    res => this.posts = posts, //returns only posts but not users
    err => console.log('something went wrong: ' + err)
  )
}
```

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65024604/1974681 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An inner pipe helps to extend the user by his posts.

```
this.service.getUsers().pipe(
  switchMap(users => {
    const postsRequests$ = this.users.map(user => this.service.getPosts(user.id).pipe(
      // example for a error catch which would lead to an empty array not breaking the forkJoin
      // catchError(err => of([])),
      map(posts => ({ ...user, posts })),
    ));

    return forkJoin(postsRequests$);
  }),
).subscribe(/* ... */);
```

Comment: Would the subscribe catch errors thrown by the inner pipe?

Comment: @F.H. Pipe is just linking together (free-point-style) one or more curried functions. So what you need to know is if `forkJoin()` errors when it's inner observables error. The answer is yes it does. If any of the inner observables error, you never get a result from `forkJoin`, just the error.

Comment: You can additionally handle errors with the rxjs `catchError` operator, I extended my answer